# quser : Error 0x000006AB enumerating sessionnames Error

Tags: powershell, security, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to create a script that will remote logoff a user based on username and computer ID. Has anyone else ran into this issue? It only happens when I'm attempting to logoff anyone else that's not my own computer.

```
#Target User
$userName = ''

#Target Computer
$computer = ""

#Finding session ID
$sessionId = ((quser /server:$computer | Where-Object { $_ -match $userName }) -split ' +')[3]

#Logging off user
Invoke-RDUserLogoff -HostServer $computer -UnifiedSessionId $sessionId






quser : Error 0x000006AB enumerating sessionnames
At line:8 char:16
+ $sessionId = ((quser /server:$computer | Where-Object { $_ -match $us ...
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error 0x000006A...ng sessionnames:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Error [1707]:The network address is invalid.
```

Comment: Try omitting `/server:$computer` from the command line if you are targeting the current computer.

Answer (score 1):

I run your script and had no problems.
sorry but i have to ask

- Is your user an administrator of the domain or remote host where you need to log off the user?
- Did you run the script by calling powershell as administrator?(Invoke-RDUserLogoff must be run with terminal with elevated privileges)

$userName = ''
$computer = ''
$sessionId = ((quser /server:$computer | Where-Object { $_ -match $userName }) -split ' +')[3]

Write-Host $sessionId

Invoke-RDUserLogoff -HostServer $computer  -UnifiedSessionID $sessionId -Force

144

PS C:\Windows\system32>